# Reset sleep time after every interrupt in python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, iot

Basically I am working on PIR sensor, when intruder is detected it goes to 1 min of sleep time. I want to reset this sleep time when  the intruder is detected during sleep time.
Below is the code:

```
`import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.IN)

try:
    while True:
        i=GPIO.input(18)
        if i==1:
            print("Intruder")
            time.sleep(60)
        elif i==0:
            print("No intruder")
            time.sleep(60)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
    exit(0)`
```

Comment: `sleep` is blocking, while you are in sleep you can't call a different function. You could use a thread though, that coun'ts till 60

Comment: i m completely new in python can u please tell me how to use thread??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using thread:

```
from threading import Thread, Event
import time

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, timeout=60):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__()
        self.intruder_spotted = Event()
        self.timeout = timeout

        self.daemon = True

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.intruder_spotted.wait(self.timeout):
                self.intruder_spotted.clear()
                print("Intruder")
            else:
                print("No intruder")



t = MyThread(60)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.IN)

try:
    t.start()
    while True:
        i=GPIO.input(18)
        if i==1:
            t.intruder_spotted.set()

        time.sleep(1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
    exit(0)
```

Comment: AssertionError: group argument must be None for now

Comment: please help me out

Comment: Updated the int of the class my Thread. It's `\__init__\` not \__ini. And the call to the parent init with super.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a raspberry pi to hand... could try this, works with keyboard input in ipython.

```
try:
    while True:
    # i=int(input('input number: '))
    i=int(i=GPIO.input(18))
        if i!=1:
            print("No intruder")
        else:
            print("Intruder")
        time.sleep(60)
```